# Angular 2 checked radio buttons ngModel

Tags: angular

I am generating radio buttons in Angular as:

```html
     <div class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
          <input type="radio" name="gender" [checked]="gender=='male'" [value]="gender" > {{gender}}
     </div>
```

This works fine, and the radio for "male" is checked by default. The problem is, I have to add the `ngModel` directive to have the field added to the form object. When I do, however, the default checked behavior doesn't work and no radio is checked by default.

```html
<input type="radio" name="gender" [checked]="gender=='male'" [value]="gender" ngModel> {{gender}}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inside-ngmodel):

> The ngModel data property sets the element's value property...

When the `ngModel` directive is used, you should set its value to initialize the input element. You can do so with data binding. Here are three possible syntaxes:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" [value]="gender" [ngModel]="genders[0]" >
<input type="radio" name="gender" [value]="gender" [ngModel]="'male'" >
<input type="radio" name="gender" [value]="gender" ngModel="male" >
```

[This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j9bfbk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) shows these various cases. You can also see an additional example where the `ngModel` value is not set. In that case, the radio button with an empty string value is checked by default, even if we try to set the `checked` property of a different button.

Comment: Instead of hard coding in 'male', I would set [ngModel]="genders[0]" to bind to the first element of the genders array. To understand why this works, I would suggest you take a look at how data binding works in Angular: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview

Comment: @user10140546 - Thanks for the useful comment.

Comment: @MrD - I added to the stackblitz the case where `ngModel` is not initialized, to show that it checks button with the empty string value.

Comment: @ConnorsFan sure thanks, I understand it works, but what I don't get is why ngModel manages the checked behaviour. Shouldn't that be attributed to [checked]?

Comment: On top of that, in select elements I can use the [selected] directive and assign a boolean to it (Eg: [selected]="name=='jon'"), so why not the same with [checked] for radios?

Comment: Angular associates a `FormControl` to the DOM element and a `RadioControlValueAccessor` acts as a bridge between the two. That latter class implements the `writeValue` method which sets the `checked` state of the element. You can find more details in [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83) and in the Angular [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/radio_control_value_accessor.ts), if you really want to know how it works internally.

Comment: By the way, the `[selected]` binding on select options appears to have the same behavior as the `[checked]` binding on the checkbox input, as you can see in [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j9bfbk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). The option is not selected when the `ngModel` directive is applied to the `select` element; we have to bind `ngModel` to a value to select the default option.